# Identify uploaded PDF is secure pdf or normal pdf file?

Tags: php

I want to check uploaded pdf file is secure pdf or not.because i want to use if file is normal file then keep it in different folder and secure in another folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have few knowlegde about if i use grep command of linux it fetch something like adobe.aps word in secure pdf and not find in normal file. but not sure about it and also how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP, and `imagick` this command will give you what you need

```
echo exec('-identify -verbose $pdf_file');
```